# Formatting a cell based on a list in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format a single cell within a worksheet, so that it is highlighted if a postcode contained within a long list of postcodes is entered. The cell I'm trying to conditionally format is E26, and the list of postcodes is A63:A2559, and the postcodes are all entered without a space (e.g. SW1A0AA).  I've tried a number of ways and formulas to conditionally format the cell (=MATCH, etc), but I keep getting error messages, or it just doesn't format the cell.  Is anyone able to help me with a formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ideally you should provide a minimum example of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this formula, if I understand your requirements correctly, it works.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($E$26,$A$63:$A$2559,0)))
```

My picture below uses different ranges, but just you so how I laid the data - to mimic what I understood as your data set. If it's different, let me know.

E6 passes the test, F6 does not.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you so much!  It works perfectly, you are a life-saver!